# Exploring all combinations of parameters

Tags: combinatorics

I often need to explore a large parameter space, e.g. making dozens of plots using a range of parameters. This looks something like:

```
explore[a, b, c, d]

a = {1, 3, 6, 8, 9}
b = {"a", "b", "c"}
c = {2, 6}
d = {"X", "I", "k", "l"}
```

I then usually use n nested loops (4 in this case) to explore all combinations of parameters, and in each loop export a plot.
I would suppose there is a more efficient, or at least a simpler way to code this. I tried Map, but would need more than one slot, and also Table, but could not fully reproduce exploring the entire parameter set.

Comment: Do you mean something like `explore @@@ Tuples[{a, b, c, d}]`?

Comment: That is not working. explore is a self written command, something like explore[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Module[{},], where a, b, c, d are parameters that are used in a longer and complex subprogram stored in module and executed using the explore command.

Comment: That should give you a list of all the outputs obtained by feeding all possible combinations of those parameters into your `explore` function, whatever the specifics of that function might be. Do the parameters come from a discrete set, as in your example?

Comment: That is beautiful! Working now. I just had to make some slight adjustments to values appearing only once, i.e. putting them into brackets. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Tuples` and `Subsets` and their associates are really handy when you're working with discrete sets. In your case:

```
a = {1, 3, 6, 8, 9};
b = {"a", "b", "c"};
c = {2, 6};
d = {"X", "I", "k", "l"};
explore @@@ Tuples[{a, b, c, d}]

(* Out= {explore[1, "a", 2, "X"], explore[1, "a", 2, "I"],... , explore[9, "c", 6, "l"]} *)
```

Depending on your `explore` function (i.e., if it takes a while and isn't already parallelized) and your actual parameters, you might also be able to speed things up with

```
Parallelize[explore @@@ Tuples[{a, b, c, d}], Method -> "FinestGrained"]
```

But probably not worth it if `explore` is fast already due to the overheads.

Comment: Thanks – it is worth to parallelise, and I wouldn't have done it without your hint.