# Passing a list of lists to Table

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

I have a function which takes a list of three numbers,

```
f[{i,j,k}]
```

I wish to make a table of the output for various input vectors {i,j,k}. `Table` doesn't seem to allow this. For example, I could do

```
Table[f[{i,j,k}],{i,0,1},{j,0,1},{k,0,1}]
```

but what if I don't want to include say the vectors {0,1,1} and {0,1,0}? I want to just be able to write a list of which vectors I want to use.

Comment: `Table[f[vec], {vec, listOfVecs}]`

Comment: Read about `MapThread`, or `f[#] & /@ {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}`

Comment: Try this `Table[f[v], {v, Tuples[{0, 1}, 3][[{1, 4, 6, 8}]]}]`

Comment: Thanks, I just realized I had tried the first option but forgot to enclose `listOfVecs` in brackets

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Or just `f /@ { ... }` :)

Comment: @jjc385 Hahaha, just for the sake of clarity..., ;))

Comment: Related: [159087](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159087/evaluate-function-on-a-grid?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [148936](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148936/exploring-all-combinations-of-parameters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Table` is the tool of first resort for making lists, but in this case there is a better one, [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) , aka `/@`.

`Map` moves through a list and applies a function of one variable to each element of the list, accumulating a list or what the function returns as it goes and returning the list it accumulates. Your function `f` may look like a function three arguments, but it really isn't. It is a function one argument which it restricts to forms that match the pattern `{i_, j_, k_}`. It is true that `f`'s definition can advantage of Mathematica's pattern destructing capability to map the elements of each triple given to `f` into components (called parts in Mathematica-speak) and bind them to local variables, but that doesn't change the [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) of `f` from 1 to 3.

So running `f` through a list of triples is perfect job for `Map`.

To show you how you would use it, I need some a list of integer triples and as simple that takes a triple as its argument.

```
SeedRandom[42]; data = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {5, 3}]
```

> `{{7, 1, 9}, {3, 1, 1}, {1, 7, 5}, {2, 2, 9}, {1, 4, 4}}`

```
f[{i_, j_, k_}] := i j k
```

Then

```
f /@ data
```

> `{63, 3, 35, 36, 16}`