# Mapping multiple function on list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, map

I know what you may be thinking so I use the code below to demonstrate what I intend to do.

```
a={a1,a2}
b={b1,b2}

(*What I don't want*)
MapThread[f[#1,#2]&,{a,b}]

(*Outputs {f[a1,b1],f[a2,b2]} *)

(*What I want*)
f1[x_,y_]:=f[#,y]&/@x
f2[x_,y_]:=f1[x,#]&/@y
f2[a,b]

(*Outputs {{f[a1,b1],f[a2,b1]},{f[a1,b2],f[a2,b2]}} *)
```

Basically, I want something that maps the function over every combination across the two lists that doesn't involve creating a lot of extra functions. Thank you!

Comment: While @kglr has provided the idiomatic answer given the list structure you desire (a matrix, i.e. a list of lists), normally the fastest way to find "every combination across the two lists" is `Tuples[a, b]`. Another advantage is that the resulting list is not as nested, making it easier to apply functions efficiently using vectorized operations :) Since you seem to be learning Mathematica, I just thought it would be nice to know about `Tuples` as well.

Comment: Interesting ... Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148936/exploring-all-combinations-of-parameters/148943#148943) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159087/evaluate-function-on-a-grid?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Answer (score 4):

```
Transpose[Outer[f, a, b]]
```

> {{f[a1, b1], f[a2, b1]}, {f[a1, b2], f[a2, b2]}}

Comment: Perfect, thank you!